# Receiving "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" when connecting from dotnet client to a java server

Tags: java, .net, sockets

I have a server (written in java) that listens for a connection on a specific port.
I have a client (written in c#) that connects with java server and try to send some data but the connection get reset with following error at server side.
"java.net.SocketException: Connection reset"

Below is the client side code:-

```
 public void ConnectServer()
    {
        try
        {
            if (Connect())
            {
                Broadcast("check");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    private bool Connect()
    {
        bool flag = false;
        try
        {
            if (!clientSocket.Connected)
            {
              clientSocket.Connect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMSRequestNotifierServer"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMSRequestNotifierPort"].ToString()));
                clientSocket.LingerState = new LingerOption(true,10);
                isConnected = true;
                flag = true;
            }
            else
            {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Text = ex.Message;
            flag = false;            }

        return flag;
    }

    private void Broadcast(String msg)
    {
        using (NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream())
        {
            byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();
            serverStream.Close();
            serverStream.Dispose();
            clientSocket.Close();
        }
    }
```

Can anyone point me what am i doing wrong in this code that my connection is getting reset?

One more finding in code is that while I debug to this line, it should write the data in stream and server should receive it but nothing happens:-

```
serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
```

Executing below lines will throws "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" on server side.

```
serverStream.Flush();
serverStream.Close();
```

Comment: Can you show me how clientSocket got initialized?

Comment: Let me add the code in above question

Answer (score 0):

You get this error when *sending,* not when connecting. It happens when you send to a connection that has already been closed by the peer, among other much less likely scenarios.

For example:

1. You send something that the peer didn't understand; it closes the connection; you keep writing; this is what happens next.

*Or*

2. The peer is sending something to *you* that you should be reading and you aren't, because you have already closed the socket.

Check the application protocol.

Comment: I have gone through several related answer but unable to figure out this on my above mentioned code. I have even tried out using TELNET and it worked fine connecting on the designated IP and Port.

Answer (score 0):

The original issue was in My Dotnet Client code the socket was close immediate after establishing.
For this I have use the 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19071/Quick-tool-A-minimalistic-Telnet-library

Below is the code that solved my problem

```
TelnetConnection oTelnetConnection = new TelnetConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMSRequestNotifierServer"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMSRequestNotifierPort"].ToString()));
Logger.Text += oTelnetConnection.Read();
oTelnetConnection.WriteLine("check");



// minimalistic telnet implementation
// conceived by Tom Janssens on 2007/06/06  for codeproject
//
// http://www.corebvba.be



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace MinimalisticTelnet
{
    enum Verbs {
        WILL = 251,
        WONT = 252,
        DO = 253,
        DONT = 254,
        IAC = 255
    }

    enum Options
    {
        SGA = 3
    }

    class TelnetConnection
    {
        TcpClient tcpSocket;

        int TimeOutMs = 100;

        public TelnetConnection(string Hostname, int Port)
        {
            tcpSocket = new TcpClient(Hostname, Port);

        }

        public string Login(string Username,string Password,int LoginTimeOutMs)
        {
            int oldTimeOutMs = TimeOutMs;
            TimeOutMs = LoginTimeOutMs;
            string s = Read();
            if (!s.TrimEnd().EndsWith(":"))
               throw new Exception("Failed to connect : no login prompt");
            WriteLine(Username);

            s += Read();
            if (!s.TrimEnd().EndsWith(":"))
                throw new Exception("Failed to connect : no password prompt");
            WriteLine(Password);

            s += Read();
            TimeOutMs = oldTimeOutMs;
            return s;
        }

        public void WriteLine(string cmd)
        {
            Write(cmd + "\n");
        }

        public void Write(string cmd)
        {
            if (!tcpSocket.Connected) return;
            byte[] buf = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cmd.Replace("\0xFF","\0xFF\0xFF"));
            tcpSocket.GetStream().Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        }

        public string Read()
        {
            if (!tcpSocket.Connected) return null;
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            do
            {
                ParseTelnet(sb);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeOutMs);
            } while (tcpSocket.Available > 0);
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public bool IsConnected
        {
            get { return tcpSocket.Connected; }
        }

        void ParseTelnet(StringBuilder sb)
        {
            while (tcpSocket.Available > 0)
            {
                int input = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
                switch (input)
                {
                    case -1 :
                        break;
                    case (int)Verbs.IAC:
                        // interpret as command
                        int inputverb = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
                        if (inputverb == -1) break;
                        switch (inputverb)
                        {
                            case (int)Verbs.IAC: 
                                //literal IAC = 255 escaped, so append char 255 to string
                                sb.Append(inputverb);
                                break;
                            case (int)Verbs.DO: 
                            case (int)Verbs.DONT:
                            case (int)Verbs.WILL:
                            case (int)Verbs.WONT:
                                // reply to all commands with "WONT", unless it is SGA (suppres go ahead)
                                int inputoption = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
                                if (inputoption == -1) break;
                                tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte((byte)Verbs.IAC);
                                if (inputoption == (int)Options.SGA )
                                    tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte(inputverb == (int)Verbs.DO ? (byte)Verbs.WILL:(byte)Verbs.DO); 
                                else
                                    tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte(inputverb == (int)Verbs.DO ? (byte)Verbs.WONT : (byte)Verbs.DONT); 
                                tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte((byte)inputoption);
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        sb.Append( (char)input );
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```